# Java Socket consumes 100% CPU when started receiving client request

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Socket that consumes 100% CPU, Single client always sends the data to server around 4096 bytes, at the server side I want to get client data & convert into actual form & store into database. Client sending data after every 3 Seconds. I did the following code to get client request.

```
    ServerSocket waiting = new ServerSocket(18800, 50, InetAddress.getByName("192.20.50.102"));
    while(true) {
       Socket socket = waiting.accept(); 
       new SessionHandler(socket).start();
    }
```

Client code written in C so datatypes are different than Java because of that I need to convert received bytes into actual form & insert into database. Thread class code as per follows:

```
public class SessionHandler extends Thread {

private Socket socket;

public SessionHandler(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    try {
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int tcCode = dataInputStream.readInt();
        int length = dataInputStream.readInt();
        if (tcCode == 1001) {
            System.out.println("in 1001");
            byte[] messageByte = new byte[length];
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < length) {
                int currentBytesRead = dataInputStream.read(messageByte, totalBytesRead, length - totalBytesRead);
                totalBytesRead = currentBytesRead + totalBytesRead;
            }
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageByte);
            ShortBuffer shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer();
            short[] values = new short[length / 2];
            shortBuffer.get(values);
            TCCodeOneOOOne tcCodeOneOOOne = new TCCodeOneOOOne(values);
            tcCodeOneOOOne.main(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have 1 client or there can be multiple clients?

Comment: Just single client.

Comment: Then try to get rid of `while(true)` because without it should wait until 1st client get connected

Answer (score 0):

try it as follow:

```
ServerSocket waiting = new ServerSocket(18800, 50, InetAddress.getByName("192.20.50.102"));
Socket socket = waiting.accept(); 
new SessionHandler(socket).start();
```